# Level of access to the non-root user in a container

Tags: docker, devops

Is there a possible way of making the entire file system of the container with non-root user. Because I have added a new user to the `dockerfile` and the container is up but I can see the `ROOT` as owner of all the folder accept one folder. Is my container is secured or do I need to make the entire filesystem of the container as per the newuser because anyone can login with ...

```
Docker exec -it -u root C_ID
```

to the container, I can connect with `ROOT`.

```
newuser@5f4cb14e62c9:/$ ls -lrt
total 8

drwxr-xr-x.   1 newuser newuser   40 Dec 31 04:24 app
```

The rest of the folders are showing `ROOT` as owner.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "is my container secured"? The level of access required in the container depends on your app and what/how it uses the container's filesystem.

Comment: I mean to say is it safe from the threats of unknown user logged in to the container shell. Because I can connect to container shell with newuser as well as the ROOT. So, still is it safe to mark this vulnerability mitigated??

Comment: If you can run `docker exec` at all, you can edit an arbitrary file on the host as root; there's not really anything to protect against here.  Usually root owning your container files is good, since if your process doesn't run as root, then it can't accidentally overwrite source files or other content.

Comment: I've edited this for clarity reasons, but I think it needs even more details.